# Equal numpy arrays produce different images via Pillow

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I use numpy and Pillow in a simple script for applying image filters. After implementation of convolution of an image and a kernel, some bug appeared, and I was able to reduce it to quite a tricky case.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def image_to_array(image_path : str) -> np.array:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    array = np.array(image)
    array.reshape(-1, array.shape[2])
    return array


def dont_filter_anything(matrix : np.ndarray, kernel : np.ndarray):
    matrix_out = np.zeros(matrix.shape)
    for (row_num, cell_num, channel_num), element in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
        matrix_out[row_num][cell_num][channel_num] = element
    return matrix_out


IDENTITY_FILTER = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
```

The second function just makes a copy instead of producing a result of convolution. Given these definitions, I do the following:

```
image1 = image_to_array('1.bmp')
image2 = dont_filter_anything(image1 , IDENTITY_FILTER)
assert np.all(image1 == image2)
Image.fromarray(image2 , mode='RGB').save('2.bmp')
Image.fromarray(image1 , mode='RGB').save('3.bmp')
```

Assertion says two arrays are equal, but here are the pictures:

1.bmp and 3.bmp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwwyY.png

2.bmp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz7pB.png

What can go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cause of the error is in the datatype and in the indexing.

- First, data types:

  ```
  matrix_out = np.zeros(matrix.shape)
  ```

  Creates a float array, you should replace this by:

  ```
  matrix_out = np.zeros_like(matrix)
  ```

  or

  ```
  matrix_out = np.zeros(matrix.shape, dtype=matrix.dtype)
  ```

  To ensure the `in` matrix and the `out` matrix have the same data type. By default `np.zeros` creates a floating point array.
- Second, indexing:

  ```
  matrix_out[row_num][cell_num][channel_num] = element
  ```

  Should be replaced for the appropiate (faster) [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) method:

  ```
   matrix_out[row_num, cell_num, channel_num] = element
  ```

With that, the function would be rewrited as:

```
def dont_filter_anything(matrix, kernel):
    matrix_out = np.zeros_like(matrix)
    for (row_num, cell_num, channel_num), element in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
        matrix_out[row_num, cell_num, channel_num] = element
    return matrix_out
```

And now PIL saves the image `2.bmp` properly.